# Public action method was not found on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller method:

```
public ActionResult GetResults(string viewToReturn, int resultsPerPage, 
          string classification = null, string sessionId = null, int? lastId= null)
{
               ...
}
```

Calling the method above via the following url:

```
http://localhost:63455/Home/GetResults?viewToReturn=grid&resultsPerPage=30
```

results in an exception thrown with this message:

> A public action method 'GetResults' was not found on controller
>   'MyWebSite.Controllers.HomeController'.

and here is the RegisterRoutes:

```
......    
routes.MapRoute("Home", "home/{action}/{*qualifier}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", qualifier = UrlParameter.Optional });
......
routes.MapRoute("SearchTitle", "{*path}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "SearchTitle", path = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to change your routing rules. I've tested the same action signature here and it works fine with the default route.

Comment: I need the rules because of other things. There is a rule at the end for urls that do not map to controllers. That rule takes hold and passes everything else to a specific controller. I updated the question with more details.

Comment: further details will help, indeed. One question, though: in which controller is that action implemented?

Comment: Do you have more routing rules?

Comment: Could you show your real route definitions? The code you have shown should work. The problem is in the `....` in your route definitions that unfortunately we cannot be guessing.

Comment: Thanks all, the problem, was that I had the [HttpPost] attribute on the method. I could swear that I removed it earlier, but somehow after I took a break and came back, I saw it. After removing it, everything now works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the [HttpPost] attribute on the method. I could swear that I removed it earlier, but somehow after I took a break and came back, I saw it. After removing it, everything now works fine.

Comment: Yes how confusing, this "gotcha" will surely catch new developers sooner or later. Perhaps the best practice should be AcceptVerbs only then until Microsoft fix this un-necessary limitation, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843875/what-is-the-difference-between-acceptverbshttpverbs-post-and-httppost