# System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET") vs System.Web.Http.HttpGet

Tags: c#, get

What exactly is the difference between

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public string[] SomeArray(string someString)
    {
```

and

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string[] SomeArray(string someString)
    {
```

and when would one use which of them, and when would one use both? I already found many examples using

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string[] SomeArray(string someString)
    {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are same.  `HttpPost/HttpGet` attributes are a shortcut for the `HttpVerbs.Post/HttpVerbs.Get` since MVC 2.0.

See this :

1. [What is the difference between [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] and [HttpPost]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843875/what-is-the-difference-between-acceptverbshttpverbs-post-and-httppost)
2. [asp.net mvc - [HttpPost/HttpGet] vs. [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post/Get)]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744990/asp-net-mvc-httppost-httpget-vs-acceptverbshttpverbs-post-get)